# How to use Google Calendar API in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-calendar-api

I am making an app for an organization. The organization uses a Google Calendar to schedule all of their events. They would like me to implement the events from their calendar into the app, showing the events in a table and allowing users of the app to view RSVP to the events.

I the app registered on the Google Developer Console, but all the documentaion for getting started is in Objective-C. The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504216/how-to-get-json-from-google-calendar-aip-in-swift) seems to be the second step in my search, but I cannot find how to get the data from the google calendar.

Currently in my ViewController I have

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/email@gmail.com")
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            let dataAsNSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println(dataAsNSString)
        }
        task.resume()

    }
```

with `email@gmail.com` being the actual email of the account associated with the google calendar. Running this I receive the output saying "User Logged In" followed by user information such as name and email address, then at the end I get
 `"code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"`

Comment: When you registered your application in developers console, Did you enable calendar api? Also, is email@gmail.com is the calendar id from which you want to retreive events? what type of oauth authorization are you using in your application? Do you have access to email@gmail.com?

Comment: Yes I have enabled the calendar API. The email I am using is the calendar ID as per instructions from goole's calendar API website on retrieving the ID . I have access to the gmail account associated with that email and the calendar is public. Because it is public, and I am only using this calendar, not whomever the user of the app's calendar, I should not need oauth authorization from the user.

Comment: i need help in google calendar swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create a public API and get the API Key and  then use the code below  to set the url.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/email.gmail.com/events?maxResults=15&key=APIKey-here")
```